# Ссылка указывающая на файл

Tags: роутер, сервер

Доброго времени суток, товарищи!

*Сразу скажу, что с подобным я сталкиваюсь впервые, могу путать понятия и, наверняка, покажусь очень глупым.*

Что есть:
маршрутизатор TP-Link TL-ER604W
Сервер на базе Windows Server 2008
Сервер выходит во внешние воды интернета через маршрутизатор

Пролог: некоторые товарищи должны забирать у нас некоторые файлы, и требуют для этого прямую ссылку для скачивания этих файлов. Можно было бы выгружать эти файлы на всякие яндекс диски, но как уже упоминалось - у нас есть сервер, специально для этого купленный.

Вопрос: Как можно это все сделать?

Сейчас основная загвоздка состоит в том, что сервер не напрямую выходит в интернет, а через маршрутизатор.

Большая просьба либо самим все объяснить, либо дать материалы и статьи по теме. Любая помощь приветствуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет [port forwarding](http://www.google.ru/search?q=port+forwarding), скорее всего даже [так](https://www.google.ru/search?q=port+forwarding+tp-link). Ещё потребуется [настройка веб-вервера](https://www.google.ru/search?q=windows+2008+web+server).. и всё )

1. Делаете веб-сервер на своём виндовсе
2. Настраиваете на роутере проброс 80-го порта на ip-адрес сервера
3. Выкладываете файлы на сервер, которые должны одинаково стать доступны как по локальному, так и по внешнему ip-адресу.

это конечно всё при условии, что провайдер уже даёт вам "белый" адрес.

Comment: Большое спасибо, будем разбираться.